# Is Thor: Ragnarok the first time we've seen this happen to The Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

Towards the end of Thor: Ragnarok, when Hulk is fighting

> Fenris

we see his (Hulk's) leg pierced

> by Fenris' fang,

and some blood seeping out into the water.

A) Is this the first time in the MCU that the Hulk has bled or had his skin pierced. (IIRC Banner cut his finger in the first Hulk film, but that's not the Hulk)

B) Was there any significance to the bite, or the bleeding - it seemed like the camera lingered on the shot a little longer that I would have expected?

Comment: I think there is some significance to us specifically being shown his skin getting pierced. Speculation,but could be that Hulk is losing power. I hope it gets answered in IW.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a word, no. His skin was also pierced during a fight with The Abomination in The Incredible Hulk (2008)

The idea is that while he's largely invulnerable to we mere mortals, creatures of similar strength can damage and potentially even kill him.

Comment: Don't bring up that abomination of a film :(.  Also, considering the clear camera focus, I wonder if they are getting the general moviewatcher attuned to this for the affinity wars and what could happen

Comment: @Naib So, it is called "affinity wars" now? lol

Comment: Well no... Stupid auto correct :(. Infinity wars....

Comment: @Naib, that should be the name of the inevitable dating show spin-off.

Comment: LOL. I have now only seen 3 minutes of that movie and agree that it is terrible. Was it a direct to SYFY release? Looks to be on par with Mega Python vs. Gatoroid

Answer (score 23):

While it isn't a puncture wound, the Hulk does get a tooth knocked out by Stark in the Hulk-buster suit:

[image: Hulk spitting tooth]

Comment: +1 for giving an answer not from the movie that never happened.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a few times in the comics where the Hulk has been cut by someone or something. Wolverine's claws can cut hulk, and IIRC he was impaled with a large sword on Sakaar.
I think it's a case of needing to be extremely strong or having a weapon that is sharp/strong enough to do the damage. But he heals quickly too so most wounds aren't a problem.

Comment: Can you provide some examples from the MCU where this happens? The scope, unfortunately, doesn't include the comics.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's a nod to the comic lore based movie, planet hulk, in which hulk gets cut, and his blood heals the dead planet. It might be where we see our new mcu hulk's movie take place.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It pretty directly answers this: "Was there any significance to the bite, or the bleeding - it seemed like the camera lingered on the shot a little longer that I would have expected?". Granted it's unsourced and unreferenced, but it is certainly relevant to the Question.